# PHP CRON Email Sending CPU Intensive

Tags: php, mysql, email, apache2, smtp

I'm running an Amazon EC2 'Large' instance - Ubuntu Natty x64 with PHP5 and MySQL. We execute a PHP script via CRON - this sends an email list (2000-4000 emails) using SMTP/PHPMailer.

The server runs very slowly (several of these CRON jobs run in parallel) and it's making the CPU go to 100%. Memory usage is low (only ~600mb / 8gigs used) and each CRON job takes a significant chunk of CPU%, for example 20-30% each with 4-5 running in parallel.

Trying to pinpoint the issue, I ran slow query log in MySQL but nothing caught my attention. How should I go about narrowing down the cause of this CPU usage? Is SMTP/email just that CPU intensive or is it a sign that there is a programming or server issue? Thanks!

[image]

**EDIT:** The issue is resolved. There was a trivial (of course) bug that caused emails to 'grow' (some of the previous email content was being injected into the next email) - so the email pre-processing got more and more ridiculous with each subscriber. The resulting emails had hundreds/thousands of tracking images which all hit our server simultaneously when opened i.e. 'display images' in gmail. After fending off the self-inflicted DDoS attack and two days of no sleep, I am going to enjoy a bottle of Captain Morgan while contemplating various choices I've made in life.

Comment: Does the PHP script run continously in loop to send the 4000 emails, or it stops and restarts repetitively ? Sometimes repeated triggering of a PHP file as command line script may cause CPU intensive operations to generate opcode.

Comment: Each CRON job runs once a minute, but it only sends 'one' list (4k emails) and then stops. During the execution of this list, the PHP script loops through 4000 emails, sets up some information, and makes an SMTP connection to send each email individually.

Comment: First thing I'd do is comment out the line that actually queues the email and then run the whole process again to see what happens. I.e., run all the code to generate the message content, but don't actually send the message. This will at least tell you if it's the generation or the sending that's causing a problem.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I just tried what you suggested. It loops through the emails in about 10-15 seconds. How about the SMTP connection - if it's SSL or TLS instead of unencrypted, will that make a huge difference?

Comment: SSL/TLS shouldn't make *that* much of a difference. I suspect that you're sending the emails to an SMTP service on localhost? If this is the case, I'd seek to edit your mail server configuration and disable anti-spam checks for locally generated mails -- I'll wager that it's doing a ton of them, over and over, for every message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that can cause this (Non-exhaustive list):

1. Non block IO with the SMTP server.
2. Implementation of SMTP library used in php with long strings manipulation/long files encoded every loop (remember: the protocol must be corrected formatted, and this is checked/encoded every time you call the send method by many other methods).
3. One (or more) query per mail.

Try measuring the time spent on each operation performed inside the loop.

You can use a simple `$start = microtime (true)` and `printf (___FILE__.':'.__LINE__.": here after % 0.8f seconds\n", microtime(true) - $start);` to a debug file or another profiling tool.

Try to reduce protocol formatting/encoding time.

Not allow more than *Number of cores in your machine here* instances of php scripts running simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

First, establish exactly which programs are taking 100% CPU.

If it's the PHP interpreter then there has be something wrong in your code - an SMTP client should never manage to reach 100% utilisation because a lot of the time it'll be limited in throughput by the SMTP server.

Comment: Can you give me more input - how do I find out if it's the interpreter? I run htop command on linux and I see the CRON jobs as #1-#4. By the way I am running PHP-APC (does this affect the command line/CRON or just Apache?)

Answer (score 1):

It may not be limited just to php... is the SMTP server you are connecting to on the local box? Are you running out of sockets? Are the requests blocking themselves?

Usually for things like what are are doing, a queue based approach is usually best.

Have you though about using a third party service for sending mail, where all you do is send a API HTTP request? There are several benefits to this, most of these services have relationships setup with mail servers so that your emails actually get to inboxes, and your SMTP server does not get blacklisted as spammy. Amazon has a service that can do this, so do others like [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com).